# jquery element on hover if CHILD has class, CHILD do something

Tags: jquery, children

I need to find a way of just show the children of hovered li.

I've this

```
$('.menu.horizontal li').hover(function(event) {
                        if(event.currentTarget === this) {
                            $(this).addClass('hover');
                            if($(this).hasClass('pai') && $(this).hasClass('hover')) {
                                $(this).find('.nivel_1').css('display', 'block');
                                $(this).find('li nivel_1').css('display', 'block');
                            } else {
                                $('li nivel_1').css('display', 'none');
                                $('.nivel_1').css('display', 'none');
                                $(this).removeClass('hover');
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

my element on hover does check for the class 'pai' and shows the .nivel_1, but if I've more .nivel_1 they are all showed... so I need to just show hovered element children.
How do I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `hover()` jQuery function to add a class to the `<li>` when the user hovers. And then you can use css to show/hide the child elements.

```
$('li').hover(
    function() { $(this).addClass('hover'); },
    function() { $(this).removeClass('hover'); }
);
```

And then use the following CSS:

```
li *       { display: none; }
li.hover * { display: block; }
```

Comment: didn't understand your solution, sorry

Comment: I did understand now, amazing, works pretty good, thanks.  Didn't know about that * in css, is the same as li and all is children, right? Thanks

Comment: Hello, can you please see this http://www.brvr.net/menu/   how to avoid having the background of top element not growing down on hover without using images. is there any css trick to do so? thanks.

Comment: It might be best to create a new question for this.

Comment: here it is  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687512/css-sub-menus-positioning-without-deform-original-menu

Answer (score 1):

```
if(event.currentTarget === this) {
    if($(this).hasClass('pai')) {
        $(this).find('> .nivel_1').css('display', 'block');

        // This line doesn't actually make sense so I've commented it out
        //$(this).find('li nivel_1').css('display', 'block');
    }
}
```

Assuming that this code is being run in the `mouseover` part of the hover event.

Comment: You also need to hide the children when the hover stops.

Comment: this is good, but now I've a problem, it shows novel_1, but of we have another li with class .pai, on hover everything his showed, I've edited the initial code

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean but I've taken a guess, check the updated code above

Comment: Hello, not yet, but now I understand a'r answer, it's amazing what just those little lines can do.